# invalid_annotation_target hides other errors

Tags: flutter, dart

In my `analysis_options.yaml`, I have enabled the `invalid_annotation_target` rule like so:

```
  rules:
    invalid_annotation_target: ignore
```

My project was displaying 0 problems. But I was starting to suspect that something was behaving strangely and I disabled the rule. More than 30 errors were found in my project, among which most of them were:

- file_names
- non_constant_identifier_names
- avoid_returning_null_for_void
- prefer_const_constructors
- ...

I do now understand why there errors are not displayed when `invalid_annotation_target` is set to `ignore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put [`invalid_annotation_target`](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#invalid_annotation_target) in analyzer errors, not linter rules. So your `analysis_options.yaml` should look like this:

```yaml
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

analyzer:
  errors:
    invalid_annotation_target: ignore
```

This will allow the linter rules you mentioned above to work back as normal.

More info on customizing static analysis and its behavior: https://dart.dev/tools/analysis

Comment: Right, I did not see that the rule was in the wrong place. Thanks!